# How to check if a value is partial, full, or none based on multiple values

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, countif

I have a column of names and a column called is broke rules.

- If the person has both broken the rule at lease once and also followed the rule at least once = `partial`
- If a person has always broken the rule = `rule breaker`
- If a person has always followed the rule = `rule follower`

I know how I would do this programmatically in python or something, but how do I check their actual rule breaking status in excel?

| name | broke rule |
| --- | --- |
| bob | no |
| bob | no |
| jane | no |
| sam | yes |
| jane | yes |
| jake | no |
| bob | yes |
| paul | no |

The result I want

| name | broke rule | rule breaking status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bob | no | partial |
| bob | no | partial |
| jane | yes | rule breaker |
| sam | yes | rule breaker |
| jane | yes | rule breaker |
| jake | no | rule follower |
| bob | yes | partial |
| paul | no | rule follower |
| jake | no | rule follower |

I have this formula but it only tells me if the are a `rule follower` or have broken the rule at least once.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"No"),"Broken rule at least once","Rule follower")
```

Comment: *If a person has broken the rule at least once but also has not broken the rule at least once = partial* - sounds like it needs editing? If you know how you would do it in Python then you should add that sample Python code to your question.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie I edited the question to make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definitions mean you can calculate `Times rule followed / Total times attempted` for each person. If that number's `0`, the person's a `rule breaker`. If it's `1`, the person's a rule follower. Otherwise, they're `partial`.

So, given your layout (and assuming the data has the header row), we can write `C2` as:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A, $A2, $B:B, "yes") / COUNTIF($A:$A, $A2)
```

`$A:$A` is the range of names and `$B$:$B` is the range of Boolean values. You can then write `D2` as:

```
=IF(C2=1, "rule breaker", IF(C2=0, "rule follower", "partial"))
```

Comment: `=IF(C2=0, "rule follower", IF(C2=1, "rule breaker", "partial"))` because the count is `Times rule broken`...

Answer (score 0):

Based on @crcvd formula, enter this formula in `C2`:

```
= LOOKUP( INT( 10 * COUNTIFS($A:$A, $A2, $B:$B, "yes") / COUNTIF($A:$A, $A2) ),
 {0,"rule follower";1,"partial";10,"rule breaker"} )
```

Actually this one also works:

```
= LOOKUP( COUNTIFS($A:$A, $A2, $B:$B, "yes") / COUNTIF($A:$A, $A2),
 {0,"rule follower";0.01,"partial";1,"rule breaker"} )
```